# SHLD+BSR decoder?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, decoding, huffman-code

Reading the following [blog post](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=205). A so called "SHLD+BSR" huffman decoder is mentioned, which is then further expanded to `MOV, MOV, SHLD, OR, BSR, MOV, SHR, MOV, OR, ADD, ADC`, however I have not found any reference or source code that describes such decoding. Does anyone know what decoding method is referred?

Comment: I've just spent half an hour looking at the source of 2 jpeg decoders, but I haven't found anything relevant.

Comment: OK I just hit paydirt in VirtualDub's HuffYuv decoder (see Meia\source\decode_huffyuv.cpp). I'll try to understand it so I can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really succeeded at understanding this method for decoding huffman codes, but the relevant "inner loop" here contains something like this (edited slightly to make the SHDL and BSR obvious):

```
uint32 posidx = pos >> 5;
uint32 code = src32[posidx];
uint32 extrabits = src32[posidx + 1];
SHLD(code, extrabits, pos);
code |= 1;
uint32 idx = BSR(code);
uint8 *p = (const uint8 *)(table->mBsrLenTable[idx] + 
                           2*(code >> table->mBsrShiftTable[idx]));
result = p[0];
pos += p[1];
```

That accounts for the `MOV, MOV, SHLD, OR, BSR, MOV, SHR, MOV` but then I'm not sure anymore. I *think* the `ADD` refers to the multiplication by 2, the `ADC` is actually a trick to add `p[1]` to `pos` and the `OR` joins the `mBsrLenTable` entry and the rest of the code, but that seems to be in the wrong order and then the `OR` would correspond with an addition in the source. Perhaps I shouldn't do this sort of thing after midnight..

You'd probably better take a look at the source yourself, because to be honest, my answer is useless. I got it here: [sourceforge.net/projects/virtualdub/files/virtualdub-win/1.9.11.32842/VirtualDub-1.9.11-src.7z](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualdub/files/virtualdub-win/1.9.11.32842/VirtualDub-1.9.11-src.7z/download) look for the file `src\Meia\source\decode_huffyuv.cpp`, it starts with the table initializing and the actual decoding is in a macro called `DECODE`, about 200 lines down.